# Elisp function to replace underscores for white spaces in the current line

Tags: elisp

I'm trying to write a very simple function to replace all the underscores in the current line for whites paces.
This is what I have so far

```
  (select-current-line)
  (exit-minibuffer)
  (query-replace "_" " " nil (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active) (region-beginning)) (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active) (region-end)))
```

But I get the following message:

```
No catch for tag: exit, nil
```

I'm not very convinced that using query-replace in an active selection is the best way, but I am not a elisp programmer at all.

Any ideas?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Based in the answers below, this is the piece code that I ended using:

```
  (let ((end (copy-marker (line-end-position))))
    (while (re-search-forward "_" end t)
      (replace-match " " nil nil)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C-h f query-replace RET` doesn't say what I wanted to quote, but `C-h f perform-replace RET` does:

```
Don't use this in your own program unless you want to query and set the mark
just as `query-replace' does.  Instead, write a simple loop like this:

  (while (re-search-forward \"foo[ \\t]+bar\" nil t)
    (replace-match \"foobar\" nil nil))
```

As for limiting it to the current line, the best way to do it is to use the second arg of `re-search-forward`:

```
(let ((end (copy-marker (line-end-position))))
  (while (re-search-forward \"foo[ \\t]+bar\" end t)
    (replace-match \"foobar\" nil nil)))
```

Notice the use of `copy-marker` because the position of the end-of-line will keep changing as you modify the line, so you don't want to keep the position as a plain integer but as a marker (which is tied to a place in the text).
A common alternative is to go backwards (since insertion/deletions only affect positions after the change):

```
(end-of-line)
(let ((beg (line-beginning-position)))
  (while (re-search-backward \"foo[ \\t]+bar\" beg t)
    (replace-match \"foobar\" nil nil)))
```